# Find value of link source using advanced segment

Tags: google-analytics

I want to see how many transactions Facebook provides and the value of these in a webshop.

I have tried to do this in two different ways:
When I use the filter box and write facebook, i get 20 transactions from 30.000 visits.

But,
When i add an advanced segments (Include source containing facebook), I get 60 transactions from 25.000 visits.

How can i verify which one is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check your tracking code for proper setup, in most cases it is a reason for this kind of trouble (use ga debugger for chrome or at least firebug's network monitoring).
2. Check that you're comparing the same time periods. Consider data sampling inaccuracy if you deal with a high traffic volume.
3. For verification purposes try to mark your facebook links with utm tags and track your visits/transactions in Campaigns report.

Comment: 1. I have checked the tracking code setup and received no complaints related to his.
2. It is the same time period. 
3. We have begun marking facebook links with utm tags, but that has not been done last year.